# How to log command in ssh sessions?

Tags: bash, logging, ssh, debian, telnet

I have a `debian` server which users `ssh` to it and do `telnet` sessions on it.
My requirement is `log` all the users commands executions and also the commands run in the `telnet` sessions.

I found `script` software while searching for a solution for this and it do what I want.

I tried testing it by adding following line to `/home/username/.profile` but it runs 2 `script` processes and need to run `exit` twice to exit from `ssh` session.

```
Log commands in each session
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]] ; then
    script test.txt
fi
```

Is anyone know why is this happen or how to fix it, or better solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Enable auditing. This might help: [Simple example auditd configuration?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/4629)

Comment: Hi @Cyrus, I checked that too but that wont log the telnet session content. Thats why I choose 'script'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exec:

```
exec script test.txt
```

Comment: Actually this solved the issue. Users don't have to exit twice from ssh session. Thanks for that. But I still see 2 script processes.